# How to prevent SQL injection when dealing with dynamic table/column names?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-injection

I am using jdbc PreparedStatement for data insertion.

```
Statement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
"INESRT INTO" + tablename+ "("+columnString+") VALUES (?,?,?)");
```

***tablename*** and ***columnString*** are something that is dynamically generated.

I've tried to parameterise tablename and columnString but they will just resolve to something like 'tablename' which will violate the syntax.

I've found somewhere online that suggest me to lookup the database to check for valid tablename/columnString, and cache it somewhere(a Hashset perhaps) for another query, but I'm looking for better performance/ quick hack that will solve the issue, perhaps a string validator/ regex that will do the trick.

Have anyone came across this issue and how do you solve it?

Comment: You need to quote them, SQL Server `[]` MySQL ` or with `"` depending on DB

Comment: What's the nature of this "dynamic generation"? Is it from a trusted source? Do you need to handle table names with spaces in etc?

Comment: @JonSkeet it is from a trusted source. a database which I have extracted earlier, which can either send an event to trigger this insertion or the insertion can be triggered manually. In the latter case, someone might alter the extracted data before inserting. For the second question, I'd want it to be as generic as possible.

Comment: @lad2025 the db is any db that is jdbc compliant, your way might work, if all jdbc compliant database provides some mechanism to escape that. I'm currenting testing with postgres however.

Comment: is the structure of your database so dynamic that you can't create static functions? Is there another deeper meaning with the need to parameterize your statements?

Comment: @JoSSte I'm taking each database row as a POJO and construct an insertion statement base on that. That way I can load any row of any table with any columns.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a java-guy, so, only a theory.

You can either format dynamically added identifiers or *white-list* them.

Second option is way better. Because

- most developers aren't familiar enough with identifiers to format them correctly. Say, to quote an identifier, which is offered in the first comment, won't make it protected at all.
- there could be another attack vector, not entirely an injection, but similar: imagine there is a column in your table, an ordinary user isn't allowed to - say, called "admin". With dynamically built `columnString` using data coming from the client side, it's piece of cake to forge a privilege escalation.

Thus, to list all the possible (and allowed) variants in your code beforehand, and then to verify entered value against it, would be the best.

As of `columnString` - is consists of separate column names. Thus, to protect it, one have to verify each separate column name against a white list, and then assemble a final `columnString` from them.

Comment: I can see white-list working on tablenames, but columnString? ;<

Comment: My point was to use sth like:`Statement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
"INESRT INTO" + my_qoute_function(tablename)+ "("+columnString+") VALUES (?,?,?)");` So even if the name wasn't qouted by developers, who are not familiar with qouting, it was quoted before sending to execution. The same with columnString but for each column

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that generates the sql string for you:

```
private static final String template = "insert into %s (%s) values (%s)";

private String buildStmt(String tblName, String ... colNames) {
    StringJoiner colNamesJoiner = new StringJoiner(",");
    StringJoiner paramsJoiner = new StringJoiner(",");
    Arrays.stream(colNames).forEach(colName -> {
        colNamesJoiner.add(colName);
        paramsJoiner.add("?");
    });
    return String.format(template, tblName, colNamesJoiner.toString(), paramsJoiner.toString());
}
```

Then use it...

```
Statement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(buildStmt(tablename, [your column names]));
```

Comment: I'm already doing something like this. How would this handle situation where one of the colNames is being altered to perform the attack?

Comment: I'm not sure what value the `colName` could have to perform some sort of attack you're thinking of... But you can always make some sanity checks if you want to...e.g verify that the colName is a word

Answer (score 0):

As an elaboration on @Anders' answer, don't use the input parameter as the name directly, but keep a properties file (or database table) that maps a set of allowed inputs to actual table names.

That way any invalid name will not lead to valid SQL (and can be caught before any SQL is generated) AND the actual names are never known outside the application, thus making it far harder to guess what would be valid SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best approach is to get table and columns names from database or other non user input, and use parameters in prepared statement for the rest.

Comment: Checking table and column names against the db that's the last resort I'd use, database operations are not cheap, especially when it's a remote one.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions we can apply.

1) White List Input Validation

```
String tableName;
switch(PARAM):
   case "Value1": tableName = "fooTable";
                  break;
   case "Value2": tableName = "barTable";
              break;
   ...

   default      : throw new InputValidationException("unexpected value provided for table name");
```

- By doing this input validation on tableName, will allows only specified tables in the query, so it will prevents sql injection attack.

2) Bind your dynamic columnName(s) or tableName(s) with special characters as shown below

eg:

- For Mysql : use back codes (`)

  > *Select `columnName ` from `tableName `;*
- For MSSQL : Use double codes(" or [ ] )

  > *select "columnName" from "tableName";*
  >  or 
  >   *select [columnName] from [tableName];*

Note: Before doing this you should sanitize your data with this special characters ( `, " , [ , ] )